# Integrate Google Wallet with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-docs, android-pay

I have been developing an event registration form with Google Apps script.  The form is required to add the data entries to a Google spreadsheet and process orders with Google Wallet. I have tried using HTMLServices, but it did not work.  Is there any way to integrate Google Wallet dynamically in the Google Apps Script service?  If not, will I need to use the App Engine?  And what language would be best?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a server component to handle callbacks from Google after the Wallet transactions. The server handler must be able to process XML or JSON depending on the API used.

If you're using the Google Checkout API, have a look at:

https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API
https://developers.google.com/checkout/samplecode

If you're using the Wallet for digital goods API, have a look at:

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/postback